# Sometimes Update Progress not working in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I am using Update Progress to progress loader but sometimes the loader shows
I accessing one page in two ways.

These are the 2 ways.

1 https://amol.com/abc.aspx

Working fine.

2 https://amol.com/abc.aspx?ID=1065&TypeId=1&Ronly=1

Update progress not working.

```
<div id="loading" class="divWaiting">
    <img id="loading-image" alt="progress" src="Images/progressbar.gif" />
</div>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="updProgress"
     AssociatedUpdatePanelID="Upnl"
     runat="server"
>
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div class="divWaiting">
            <img alt="progress" src="Images/progressbar.gif" />
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Upnl" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>   
        ///some code////
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnAddDocu" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind it.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (!Page.IsPostBack){
        if (Request.QueryString["IsCoderAuditor"] == "A"){
            if (Session["SelectedAuditIdForRebuttal"] != null && Session["SelectedAuditIdForRebuttal"].ToString() != ""){
                ddlRecordNumber.SelectedValue = Session["SelectedAuditIdForRebuttal"].ToString();
                ddlRecordNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe when the updatepanel is working and when it is not working?

Comment: I have already put in my question i.e. first and second

Comment: The links are not working so can’t see your examples.

Comment: When i run link without query string its working proper but with query string its not please check page load